# Is the region bounded by a point the entire plane?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is the region bounded by a point the entire plane?  Recently came across this issue in a question - for which the answer implied the affirmative.  Can someone elaborate on what the meaning of bounded is?  Is there a technical definition?

Comment: First, to even think of "boundedness", we need a way to find the "distance" between any two points? Do we have it?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh You going to need to elaborate...

Comment: The whole notion of boundedness comes from the intuition that a "bounded" set should be one such that the maximum distance between any two points should be finite (or less than some finite quantity). To establish this, we need a way to measure distance between points. Do we have it in this case?

Comment: There is no way we can have the notion of "boundedness" in terms of "bounded by a point". If you want to have one, you have to define it yourself and see to it that other intuitions do not fail at the same time.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Ok then so theres no real "official"position on what to do with a point?

Comment: No. But, I suggest you read some metric notions and then look at boundedness